# how to create hashmap in jsf xhtml

Tags: dictionary, jsf, xhtml, el

I need create or rather pass (to method) a hashmap or any map in jsf xhtml view layer.

create a list would be this way:

```
#{['value1','value2']}
```

But I find nothing about do that with map like (this does not work)

```
#{{'key1','value1','key2','value2'}}
```

I would like to do some like this

```
<h:commandButton action="#{bean.processUser({'name': 'will','lastName': 'smith'})}" />
```

Comment: Pass it as a string (make sure you use the right escaping) and then server side convert it from string to json/hashmap. But honestly, it is bad design to pass static info like this from a view to a bean. Make it fixed in the bean

Comment: @Kukeltje yes, but it's a code generator project and that supposed that code is not going to be as clean as it should. thanks for advice by the way.